# Generate OTP for mobile number verification in Node.js

Tags: node.js, one-time-password

When user registers for the app, I have to verify the mobile number. For that, I have to generate OTP and then verify the OTP which the user has submitted.

I found a library - https://www.npmjs.com/package/otplib which has a lot of options to generate an OTP.

And I found a simple answer which suggests generating random numbers and saves in database. When user submits the OTP, we will validate the OTP with the data in our DB. When should I use the library mentioned above?

I want to know the scenario to use the library? Are there any examples where the library should be used rather than generation our own numbers?

Comment: That library is for a different kind of one-time-token, the kind where the user has an app such as Authy or Google Authenticator. If you're just verifying a phone, I don't think you need it. You just need to send a (good) random code to a phone and get the user to repeat it.